# "include new items in manual filter" missing in Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel the "include new items in manual filter" is missing:

[image]

From what I can read it is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Where do I find the option to ad include new values when I have a filter applied to my pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New solution:

I just discovered if you right click in the green area on the following screenshot "Field Settings" will open this menu will contain the option:

[image]

But if you right click the red area of the pivot table "Field Value Settings" will open instead, this menu will not contain the option.

*I keep my old answer here it is probably wrong, but I have no way of testing this, so I will leave it up until disproven:
I checked my colleague's computer and he have the button to "include new items in manual filter" in his field settings.
I know the difference between our computers is that I have 64 bit Excel and he has 32 bit Excel.
I don't know if that explain reason I don't have the button, but that could be part of the reason.*

I hope this can be of value to someone in the future.